# Why do we take the absolute value in a hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Recently I studied the definition of *p*-value as

> The  *p*-value  associated with a test is the probability that we
>   obtain the observed value of the test statistic or a value that is
>   more extreme in the direction given by the alternative hypothesis,
>   when $H_0$ (null hypothesis) is true.

For a two-sided alternative, the *p*-value =$P_{H_0}[|T|\geq|t_0|]$ where $T$ is the test statistic and $t_0$ is the observed value of the test statistic. Why do we take the absolute values of $T$ and $t_0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The absolute value is taken merely to give a concise way to define extremes in both directions.  So |T|>=|t$_0$|  simply means T>=|t$_0$| or T<=-|t$_0$|.